# How to disable automatic retries in GCD?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In Google Cloud Dataflow, when a task runs into a problem it is automatically re-run a few times. The following message appears in the log:

```
Failed task is going to be retried.
```

However, while developing, the cause of the failure is almost always a bug of mine and so I would prefer for the job to be canceled instead of continuing needlessly.

Is there some setting I can use to control the retry behavior? 
Ideally this would be something in the pipeline options but I couldn't find anything [there](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/PipelineOptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible to change the number of retries when running on the Dataflow service.

However, you can use the DirectPipelineRunner to test your code locally, and that will fail immediately if your code throws an exception.